# Cannot initialize type with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, controller, viewmodel

I have 3 entities for main menus. and sub menus. I created menu view model.

My Entities:

MainMenu.cs:

```
public UstMenuler()
{
    AltMenuler = new HashSet<AltMenuler>();
}

public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public bool AktifMi { get; set; }
public int YetkiID { get; set; }
public string ControllerName { get; set; }
public string ActionName { get; set; }
public virtual Yetkilendirme Yetkilendirme { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<AltMenuler> AltMenuler { get; set; }
```

SubMenu.cs:

```
public partial class AltMenuler
{      
    public AltMenuler()
    {
        UstMenuler = new HashSet<UstMenuler>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? YetkiID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public virtual Yetkilendirme Yetkilendirme { get; set; }
}
```

MyViewModel:

```
public class MenuViewModel
{
    public UstMenuler UstMenuler { get; set; }
    public AltMenuler AltMenuler { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
dbContext = new MarkettingDbContext();

int sessionYetkiID = (int)Session["yetkiID"];
MenuViewModel menuler = new MenuViewModel();

var query = (from menu in dbContext.UstMenuler
             where (menu.YetkiID == sessionYetkiID)
             select new MenuViewModel
             {
                 menuler.UstMenuler.ID = menu.ID,
                 menuler.UstMenuler.Name = menu.Name,
                 menuler.UstMenuler.YetkiID = menu.YetkiID,
                 menuler.UstMenuler.ControllerName = menu.ControllerName,
                 menuler.UstMenuler.ActionName = menu.ActionName
             }).ToList();
```

I am getting error when I execute my query. For example my sessionID is 1, I want to take my main and submenus.

Comment: Please include more details on your error messages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is your object initializer:

```
select new MenuViewModel
{
    menuler.UstMenuler.ID = menu.ID,
    menuler.UstMenuler.Name = menu.Name,
    menuler.UstMenuler.YetkiID = menu.YetkiID,
    menuler.UstMenuler.ControllerName = menu.ControllerName,
    menuler.UstMenuler.ActionName = menu.ActionName
}
```

Firstly you're using `menuler` in the object initializer, and I'm not sure why. Next, you're trying to assign to subproperties, which even if it *did* compile, would result in a `NullReferenceException`. Collectively, that's basically not what you want to do :)

Instead, I'd use one of the two options below.

If you're happy to just copy the `UstMenuler` reference from the `menu` parameter into the new view model instance, you can do that really easily:

```
select new MenuViewModel { UseMenuler = menu }
```

Or if you want to create a new `UstMenuler` and copy properties from `menu`:

```
select new MenuViewModel
{
    UstMenuler = new UstMenuler
    {
        ID = menu.ID,
        Name = menu.Name,
        YetkiID = menu.YetkiID,
        ControllerName = menu.ControllerName,
        ActionName = menu.ActionName
    }
}
```

Either way, you don't need your `menuler` variable which you appear not to be using anywhere else.

As it sounds like you're using LINQ to Entities, it sounds like you may want to separate the database query part from the projection part. The simplest way to do that in your case is to avoid the query expression syntax, so you can call `AsEnumerable` easily. So for example:

```
var query = dbContext.UstMenuler
    .Where(menu => menu.YetkiID == sessionYetkiID)
    .AsEnumerable() // Do the projection in-process
    .Select(menu => new MenuViewModel
                    {
                        UstMenuler = new UstMenuler
                        {
                            ID = menu.ID,
                            Name = menu.Name,
                            YetkiID = menu.YetkiID,
                            ControllerName = menu.ControllerName,
                            ActionName = menu.ActionName
                        }
                    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Hello Daisy 

I tried your first solution I am getting this error on my layout page;

Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

I tried your second solution on my controller ;

The entity or complex type 'MVC.UstMenuler' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: @user9582479: This is the problem with only knowing part of your context... we didn't know what LINQ provider you were using at all. I can't tell what's wrong with the first example just based on "Error executing child request" - you'd need to get a more detailed exception. I'll edit to give a "safer" version though.

Comment: @user9582479: I've added an extra sample at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Daisy ;

select new MenuViewModel { UseMenuler = menu }

It is okey :) 

How can I take submenus relational main menu ?

Comment: @user9582479: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking, but that sounds like it should be in a new question anyway.